# mybatis - insert transaction

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

mybatis mapper code for insert:

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="Shop" useGeneratedKeys="true">
    insert into shop(email, pswd, nickname, mobile, city, create_date, status) values (#{email}, #{pswd}, #{nickname}, #{mobile}, #{city}, #{createDate}, #{status})
    <selectKey keyProperty="id" order="AFTER" resultType="long">
        select currval('shop_id_seq')
    </selectKey>
</insert>
```

The database is postgresql 9.3.

My **doubt** is: without explicity transaction, when I retrieve the id from sequence with `select currval('shop_id_seq')`, is it possible to get the wrong value if other threads are also doing insert?

I thought it won't, because currval() function runs in context of current session, not global session, but I am not that sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [*PostgreSQL: Documentation: 9.3: Sequence Manipulation Functions*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-sequence.html), the sequence function `currval`:

> Return the value most recently obtained by `nextval` for this sequence in the **current session**. (An error is reported if `nextval` has never been called for this sequence in this session.) Because this is returning a **session-local value**, it gives a **predictable answer** whether or not other sessions have executed `nextval` since the current session did.

So you will get the correct value. In another way, the sequences are non-transactional. Each session gets a distinct sequence value. The changes in the sequence can not be undone.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want to know :) I should have checked the document more carefully.